# How to find the compiled extensions modules in numpy

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I am compiling numpy myself on Windows. The build and install runs fine; but how do I list the currently enabled modules .. and modules that are not made available (due to maybe compilation failure or missing libraries)?

Answer (score 2):

numpy does not have optional components. Either the build is successful, or it fails. You can run the test suite to see if the build works.

```
$ python -c "import numpy;numpy.test()"
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.4.0.dev
NumPy is installed in /Users/rkern/svn/numpy/numpy
Python version 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Apr 23 2009, 14:49:51) [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)]
nose version 0.11.0
.....................
... etc.
```